# Видимость переменной за циклом

Tags: java

Несложная на первый взгляд задача не даёт покоя.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class First {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        go_ahead();
    }

    private static void go_ahead() {
        //запускаем рандом      
        final Random random = new Random();
        System.out.println(strings_stock.hello);        
        //запускаем сканер
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //принимаем переменную от пользователя
        int i = sc.nextInt();
        //проверка должна будет произойти не меньше одного раза
        int numGuess = 1;
        //закрываю сканер
        sc.close();
        while (true) {
            //введенное число это "потолок" для рандома
            int randomA = random.nextInt(i);
            int randomB = random.nextInt(i);
            //начинаю сравнивать
            if (randomA != randomB) {
                System.out.println();
                //объявляю о неудаче, количество попыток, загаданные цифры
                System.out.println(strings_stock.ups + strings_stock.numGuess + numGuess + strings_stock.tru);
                System.out.println(strings_stock.myRandNums + randomA + strings_stock.and + randomB);
                numGuess++;
                //если совпали выходим из цикла
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        //объявлю удачный ход и количество попыток
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(strings_stock.end + " на " + numGuess + strings_stock.tru);
        //проблема! не выдаёт значение совпавших чисел, ругается на randomA
        System.out.println(strings_stock.myRandNum + randomA);
    }
}
```

Если объявляю переменную до цикла, компилятор недоволен тем, что она дублируется. Как показать совпавшие числа?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Область видимости переменных (не считая полей класса) ограничена блоком кода в коем они объялены. Т.е. код снаружи `{}` не видит переменных, объявленных внутри `{}`

Таким образом, вам надо объявить переменную в том же блоке кода, где вы к ней обращаетесь (т.е. до цикла) или блоком выше (на уровне класса). А дублирования переменных у вас не видно.

Comment: Если перед циклом написать `int randomA;` и оставить в цикле `int randomA = random.nextInt(i);`, то ошибка будет. Надо полагать, автор об этом.

Comment: @Regent, возможно) в этом случае надо просто стереть int внутри цикла)

Comment: да, об это я и говорю.

Comment: @CoffeJava перед циклом сделайте `int randomA = 0;`, а в цикле - `randomA = random.nextInt(i);`.

Comment: если удаляю int предлагает на выбор: создать локальную переменную, поле или константу

Comment: @Regent  нет, если объявлять int randomA  = 0; до цикла то предлагает переименовать её внутри цикла.(

Comment: @CoffeJava нет, не должен предлагать. Пересмотрите мой комментарий ещё раз: в цикле должно быть `randomA = random.nextInt(i);`, а не `int randomA = random.nextInt(i);`.

Comment: @Regent Отлично, сработало )) А вас не затруднит вкратце почему не сработало или почему сработало? если есть время и желание.

Comment: @CoffeJava, в принципе нет запрета на использование одинаковых имен у переменных в разных блоках кода. Проблема была у вас в том, что вы попытались в консоль переменную эту вывести и вот тут уже компилятор не смог справиться. По идее, если вы оставите `int randomA` и до и внутри цикла, но закоментируете вывод в логи, то компилироваться будет, т.к. конфликта не станет.

Comment: Каждое слово по отдельности я понял, во едино собрать не могу. Мне судя по всему ещё долго учится до того что бы воспользоваться вашим советом. Спасибо.

Comment: я не в курсе, что такое логи и как их комментировать (

Comment: @CoffeJava, логи/stackTrace/консоль это то место, куда выводит текст System.out.print(). Закомментировать - значит в начале строки поставить `//` чтобы строка стала комментарием и не исполнялась.

Comment: консоль и комментарии это понятно, как собрать это вместе, вот вопрос...

Comment: @CoffeJava, ну типа как-то так: `int randomA = random.nextInt(i); while (true) {
            int randomA = random.nextInt(i);
            if (randomA != randomB) {
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        //System.out.println(strings_stock.myRandNum + randomA);`

Comment: @CoffeJava когда вы пишите `int randomA = 0` вы объявляете новую переменную типа `int` с значением 0, когда просто `randomA = 0` то присваиваете уже существующей переменной значение 0. В каждом блоке кода могут быть переменные с одинаковым именем и не мешать друг другу. Таким образом в первом случае у вас две разных переменных с одним именем, во втрром - одна и та же переменная. Подробнее почитайте про области видимости переменных, их инициализацию и именование.

Comment: @pavlofff отлично !) Спасибо, это была та самая "вишенка на торте" которой мне не хватало)) Всё понятно ( теперь)